# How to reorder subitems of a listviewitem?

Tags: c#, listview, subitem

so i've written a code that reorders the columns of a listview ( actually just -=1 and +=1's the display index of the selected listview column. But when i move the columns the subitems stay . they dont move. I would like the corresponding subitem to move with the column.

```
main.listView1.Columns[listBox1.SelectedIndex].DisplayIndex += 1;
listBox1.Select();
listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e); //the code for moving the column to the right

main.listView1.Columns[listBox1.SelectedIndex].DisplayIndex -= 1;
listBox1.Select();
listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e); //the code for moving the column to the left
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401/en-us) article snippet.

```
// Determine if clicked column is already the column that is being sorted.
if ( e.Column == lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn )
{
    // Reverse the current sort direction for this column.
    if (lvwColumnSorter.Order == SortOrder.Ascending)
    {
        lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Descending;
    }
    else
    {
        lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
    }
}
else
{
    // Set the column number that is to be sorted; default to ascending.
    lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn = e.Column;
    lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
}

// Perform the sort with these new sort options.
this.listView1.Sort();
```

Comment: Never freaking mind, i just realized that the stupid listview has a drag & drop listview reorder function . Sorry.